# validating password failure

Tags: php, mysql, hash, password-encryption

I went through this link http://crackstation.net/hashing-security.htm#properhashing and used the code given for php.

I am able to register new users by calling `create_hash($password)` function in the `PasswordHash.php` from the example.

Now I am trying to login by entering the newly created password, but it fails. I call the function, `validate_password($password, $good_hash)`. I pass the entered password as is and the good hashed password stored in the db as is to this function. It always returns `false`.

This is the code segment :

```
$validPwd = validate_password($password,$goodpassword) ;

if($validPwd == FALSE) {
   echo "invalid password. please retry.".$validPwd.$password."==".$goodpassword;
}
else {
   //..........
}
```

Any idea why I get into the `false` all the time? I see the correct password entered and goodpassword by `echo`'ing.

Comment: There are too many possible things to go wrong with the given information, so you'll have to go step by step and narrow things down a bit more. To start with, run create_hash() on a small simple password and hold on to the result. Then run the function again with the same password and make sure the result is the same. If that passes then, all in one script pass, run create_hash(), store in a variable, then immediately feed the password variable and the stored hash into the validate_password function and see what the result is. This eliminates the db and simplifies troubleshooting.

Comment: maybe you need to check for `boolean false` with `===` instead of `==`

Comment: what are you passing as `$goodpassword`?

Comment: Thank you @BrianDHall. I got it fixed and this is what I did based on your suggestion. First wrote an independent script with password and compared. It worked. I realized may be it's got to do with db. Then I hardcoded the password on my original registration form and it worked with db interaction. The I ruled out database too. Figured out the suspect was between the calling php and the called php. That's when I realized I was calling the create hash function with $_POST[password]. substituted that with $password and voila!

Comment: @PedroCordeiro it is the value in db column password.